# How to send row values when checkbox is clicked to struts action class

Tags: jsp, struts2

Here i need to send only checked values to struts action class.
if i check 1st row check box then i need to send only 1row values to action class or 4th then 4th row values

```
<s:iterator value="stafflistfirsttime">
    <tr >
                                                            <td>second<s:checkbox name="ckeckbox"cssClass="case chkPassport"fieldValue="%{ReferenceID}" /></td>
<td class="t" ><s:property value="ReferenceID" /></td>
<td class="stfnm"><input type='hidden' name="Name" 
value=<s:propertyvalue="teacherFirstName" />" />    
<s:property value="teacherFirstName" /></td>                                                            
<td class="bb"> <s:textfield name="Basics"                                                                  cssClass="form-control expenses" value="" size="6" /></td>
<td class="allw"><div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-1"><s:textfield name="Allowances" cssClass="form-control expenses" value="" size="6" /></div></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your existing tag with ordinary html

```
<checkbox name="ckeckbox"class="case chkPassport"value="${ReferenceID}" />
```

The `ReferenceID` should be accessible from the valueStack because of struts request wrapper.

Comment: this is a https://jsfiddle.net/fe1qxpq4/22/ , jsfiddle link it is only for reference , my problem is i am not getting how to send full row value to action class eg:if i click  Reference id 1 and 4 's check box and on clicking of submit i need to send Reference id 1 and 4  rows values to action class.

Comment: If you want to send only checked values then you should not use struts tag. Second the submit tag is used to submit the form that contains all enabled input fields. If you want to submit only part of them then you have to disable unused input fields. Otherwise you can use jquery ajax to submit data serialized manually

Comment: Even then if we disable input fields on submit we ll get  inputfeilds right??

Comment: If you disable input fields they won't be submitted. Another approach to get ids of the forms on the page and use their ids to submit those forms that has a checked checkbox.

Comment: if you want to submit n random rows you can't enclose them in one form. Instead each form occupies all input fields on the row and you know what form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

As per your fiddle  -- working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/fe1qxpq4/19/)

```
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Month</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
              <s:select headerKey="" headerValue="--Select--"
                 list="#{'1':'JAN', '2':'FEB', '3':'MAR','4':'APR','5':'MAY','6':'JUN','7':'JUL', '8':'AUG', '9':'SEP', '10':'OCT','11':'NOV', '12':'Dec'}"
                 name="selctmonth" cssClass="form-control" />
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Year</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="input-group input-append date" id="yearPicker">
                 <s:textfield name="selctyear" cssClass="form-control"
                    id="yearofExam" />
                 <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-1">
              <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="row_dim">
        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
           <table class="table table-bordered display nowrap"
              id="dataTS">
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;"></th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Reference
                       id
                    </th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Employee
                       name
                    </th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Month</th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Year</th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Basics</th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Allowances</th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Edit</th>
                    <th style="background: #00a8a8; color: white;">Submit</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <s:iterator value="firsttime">
                 <tr id="ReferenceID_1">
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="age" value="1" /></td>
                    <td class="t ReferenceID"> 1</td>
                    <td class="stfnm">
                       <s:property
                          value="ffff" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="mnt">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-xs-2">
                             <s:select id="Name"
                                list="#{'1':'01', '2':'02', '3':'03','4':'04','5':'05','6':'06','7':'07', '8':'08', '9':'09', '10':'10','11':'11', '12':'12'}"
                                name="selctmonth" cssClass="form-control" />
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="yr">
                       <h5 class="yearforpay"></h5>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bb"> <input type="text" name="allowance"
                       class="form-control expenses" value="" size="6" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="netsalary"><input
                       class="form-control expenses_sum" size="6"></td>
                    <td class="wday">
                       <s:property value="TableID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>Unpaid</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr id="ReferenceID_2">
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="age" value="2" /></td>
                    <td class="t ReferenceID">2</td>
                    <td class="stfnm">
                       <s:property
                          value="ffff" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="mnt">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-xs-2">
                             <s:select id="Name"
                                list="#{'1':'01', '2':'02', '3':'03','4':'04','5':'05','6':'06','7':'07', '8':'08', '9':'09', '10':'10','11':'11', '12':'12'}"
                                name="selctmonth" cssClass="form-control" />
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="yr">
                       <h5 class="yearforpay"></h5>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bb"> <input type="text" name="allowance"
                       class="form-control expenses" value="" size="6" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="netsalary"><input
                       class="form-control expenses_sum" size="6"></td>
                    <td class="wday">
                       <s:property value="TableID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>Unpaid</td>
                    <td>
           </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button"
           class="btn btn-info use-address1 submitbtn">Submit</button></td>
        <!-- Modal 2 -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
              Modal content
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                          id="closeMark">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Reference</label>
                          <div class="col-xs-5 ">
                             <input type='text' name="examDate1" class="form-control"
                                id="Referenceid"/> 
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <br>  
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Allowance</label>
                          <div class="col-xs-5 ">
                             <input type='text' name="examDate1" class="form-control" id="allowanceid"
                                /> 
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div align="center">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary updatemodul"
                             >Update</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                          data-dismiss="modal" id="modalReset">Close</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->


<script>

        $(document).on("click", ".editbuttton", function() {
            var RecordId = $(this).closest("tr").find(".ReferenceID").text();
            $("#myModal #Referenceid").val(RecordId);


        });
        $(document).on("click", ".submitbtn", function() {

            jsonObj = [];
            var chboxCheck = false;
            $('#dataTS').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                chboxCheck = true;
                var $this = $(this);
                var ClosestTr = $this.closest("tr");
                var Employeename = ClosestTr.find(".stfnm").html();
                var EmployeeId = $this.val();
                item = {}
                item["EmployeeId"] = EmployeeId;
                item["Employeename"] = Employeename;
                jsonObj.push(item);

            });
            console.log(jsonObj);
            if (!chboxCheck) {
                alert("please check atleat one checkboc");
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submitonebyonestaff',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: jsonObj,
                success: function(data, success) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });

        var ReferenceAllow = '';
        $(".updatemodul").click(function() {
            ReferenceAllow = $("#allowanceid").val();
            console.log(ReferenceAllow);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submitonebyonestaff',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {


                },

                success: function(data, success) {
                    console.log(ReferenceAllow);
                    var ReferenceID = 1;
                    var UpdateHtml = "<td>" + ReferenceID + "</td><td></td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><td class='netsalary'><input class='form-control expenses_sum Test' size='6' value='" + ReferenceAllow + "'></td><td></td><td></td><td>Test</td>";
                    $(document).find("#ReferenceID_" + ReferenceID).empty().append(UpdateHtml);
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');


                    alert("sucess")

                },
                error: function(data, error) {
                    alert("error")

                }

            });

        });


</script>
```